# Inconsistent behavior of select for socket between Linux and BSD

Tags: linux, macos, sockets

I am building a cross platform socket program under MacOS (FreeBSD) and Linux, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
   fd_set rfds;
   fd_set wfds;
   struct timeval tv;
   int retval;

   int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   FD_ZERO(&rfds);
   FD_ZERO(&wfds);
   FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
   FD_SET(fd, &wfds);

   tv.tv_sec = 1;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   retval = select(fd + 1, &rfds, &wfds, NULL, &tv);

   printf("ready sockets = %d\n", retval);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It's very simple, it creates a `socket`, and use `select` to see if it's either readable or writable.

If I run it under MacOS

```
ready sockets = 0
```

You will see the program blocks for 1 second and it prints socket ready. But if you run it under Linux, you will see it prints out

```
ready sockets = 2
```

immediately. Which sounds very odd to me, since the socket just created, there is nothing to read or write, but yet `select` function told me it's ready to read and write, how come they behave differently?

Comment: Obviously a bug in Linux, but it's a very strange thing to do, they might just argue that it's an invalid case when you report it.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's "obviously" a bug in Linux.  I would argue that calling `select()` on a disconnected socket is a bug in Fang-Pen's code.

Comment: @larsks It's both. Reporting readiness on a socket that isn't ready is a bug, and so is selecting on it.

Comment: @larsks I don't know if this is my bug or Linux's bug, but at least I didn't see any document saying anything about select on a newly created socket. The reason I am doing so is that I want to call connect on it later, I have abstraction allows me to register handler to the socket for reading and writing events. And if before I call connect, it triggers read and write events, which will be a trouble, and the handler got called before anything happened. Then I can only register handler to the selector after socket is connected.

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll have to do: only register the socket after `listen(), accept()`, or `connect()`.

Comment: @larsks I should have said 'so is selecting on a non-listening unconnected socket'.